# Is there an iPad app which will let me use the orientation of my iPad to emulate a joystick on PC?

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, windows, remote-control

I would like to be able to play games on my Windows PC using a joystick instead of keyboard and/or mouse as controls. However I don't have a joystick. I could buy one, but I want to see if I could use my iPad as a joystick. I want to be able to tilt the iPad and the angle of the iPad to be the joystick input to the computer. It should be possible to make an app like this; the question is whether anyone has made an app like this.

There is an app called [Custom Control Pad](http://www.frozenpepper.it/ccp-custom-control-pad/) which works as a joystick input to a computer. However, it does not appear to have a feature to read the iPad's orientation - you can only use an on screen joystick or sliders. I've tried contacting the makers of CCP but their forum does not appear to be working.

**EDIT:**

A year later I again wanted to use an iPad as a joystick, so I created the program myself. It can be found at https://github.com/That-Cool-Coder/tablet-tilt-joystick. In some ways it's better than what I asked for because it will work on any mobile device, not just an iPad. Not posting as an answer because it only works on Linux and the question specifies Windows.